# Sending picture in Android (Socket Programming)

Tags: android, image, sockets, send

I'm trying to receive a Picture on my Android phone from Server using socket programming.I use this code but `in.read()` in 4th line always returns -1.
How can I fix this problem?

**Client Code:**

```
try {
   x = new byte[picLength2];                          
   int current = 0;
   int byteRead = in.read(x, 0, x.length);                          
   current = byteRead;
   do {
      byteRead = in.read(x, current, (x.length - current));
      if (byteRead >0) {
        current += byteRead;
      }
   } while (byteRead > -1);
}catch (IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Server Code:**

```
 try {
                                            
     File myFile = new File("C:/onlinegame/null.jpg");
     mybytearray = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
     bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 try {
     DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     out.write(mybytearray);
        
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
```

Comment: where is your server IP and all?? and what is this C:/onlinegame/null.jpg

Comment: i just write the send and receive part . other parts work properly and just this part doesn't. i use my laptop as a server and this address is the place that my picture was saved in